# How do I disable JS only on specific pages?

Tags: javascript, ublock-origin

There are sites archived on the Wayback Machine with broken JS.

uBlock origin allows disabling JS on the whole site: `no-scripting: web.archive.org true`, but it is an overkill.  Is there a way do it only on some pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`My rules` only support host and type based blocking. So no possibility for e.g. including path. See [documentation](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Dynamic-filtering:-rule-syntax).

You can block JS in `My filters` section though. Here's an example:

```
||web.archive.org/*/https://superuser.com$csp=script-src 'none'
```

This would block scripts on all pages concerning just https://superuser.com main page due to [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src) enforcing it.

For more accuracy, you can also utilize regexes:

```
/^https?:\/\/web\.archive\.org\/.*?\/\d+\/https?:\/\/superuser\.com.*/$csp=script-src 'none'
```

This would block all superuser subpages with a specific date, so e.g. [this archived page](http://web.archive.org/web/20230208161720/https://superuser.com/questions/) but not this [date choice page](http://web.archive.org/web/20230000000000*/https://superuser.com/questions/) that doesn't match.

You can also change the `$csp` ending to more accurate blocking, see [documentation](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Static-filter-syntax#extended-syntax) for all possible syntax parts, i. e. `$inline-script`.

Answer (score 0):

Though I've not tried this, you can click the uBlock Origin icon, select gears to open Dashboard, and edit a line manually to be more specific.

for example change a line beginning,

> http://web.archive.org

to

> http://web.archive.org/web/20131014212210/https://stackoverflow.com/

if that's the page in question.

Please let me know if that works for you... if  not, I'll delete this answer.